# How to change scroll Bar Style

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, jscrollpane

I like to know how to add a custom scroll bar to a table (item table).
I have written the code below. Once 10 items are added the scroll bar appears,but i like a custom scroll pane to appear (eg: a scroll  like in fb).

```
<form action="#" method="get"><style type="text/css">.carttable{width: 252px;height: 200px;overflow: auto;}
```

Comment: i think you prefer jquery..

Comment: This is a great solution: http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/ Give it a try

Answer (score 1):

The [Nicescroll 3](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/index.html) suggestion of Cmacu works very well! Did you tried? It have many nice features for personalize the appearance of the bar and also support horizontal bar, it support many browsers on desktop and mobile version. You can find some examples here: [Live Examples](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/demo.html).
The download file have many others examples in HTML files for you know how it works.

Just put loading script tag on header after jQuery and then call the function when page is loaded.

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>
```

**JavaScript file**

```
$(document).ready(

  function() { 

    $("html").niceScroll({cursoropacitymax:0.6, cursorwidth:10px, horizrailenabled:false});

  }

);
```

For personalize the appearance of the scroll bar you have to pass inputs on the function as the example above. You can find all the availables inputs at the end of the main page, section "Configuration parameters".

Comment: You really need to provide  more comprehensive answer than this. Perhapssome examples or links to where the person can find out more.

Comment: Well, all this can be found in the link that Cmacu provided. I just want to let people know that it work well and it's easy. Sorry for my post i will comment the code to show how easy is that.

Answer (score 0):

header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="sourcecode">
$j=jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function()
{
    $j('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({
    showArrows: true,
    autoReinitialise: true});
});
</script>
```

css

/* Styles specific to this particular page */

```
.scroll-pane
 {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
overflow: auto;
 }
```

/*
 * CSS Styles that are needed by jScrollPane for it to operate correctly.
 *
 * Include this stylesheet in your site or copy and paste the styles below into your   stylesheet - jScrollPane
 * may not operate correctly without them.
 */

```
.jspContainer {
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
 }

.jspPane {
 position: absolute;
 }

  .jspVerticalBar {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 none;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
top: 0;
width: 16px;
 }
  .jspHorizontalBar {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 none;
bottom: 0;
height: 16px;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
}


 .jspVerticalBar *, .jspHorizontalBar * {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.jspCap {
display: none;
}
.jspHorizontalBar .jspCap {
float: left;
 }
.jspTrack {
background: url(scroll-images/groen-streepje.png) 0 0 repeat-y scroll;
position: relative;
 }

.jspDrag {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ACC314;
cursor: pointer;
left: 0;
position: relative;
top: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
 }

.jspHorizontalBar .jspTrack, .jspHorizontalBar .jspDrag {
float: left;
height: 100%;
}

  .jspArrow {
  background: url(scroll-images/pijltjes.png) 0 0 no-repeat scroll;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: block;
 text-indent: -20000px;
  }

  .jspArrow.jspDisabled {
  background: url(scroll-images/pijltjes.png) 0 -9px no-repeat scroll; /* ander kleur pijltje */
cursor: default;
  }

.jspVerticalBar .jspArrow {
height: 9px;
 }

 .jspHorizontalBar .jspArrow {
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 width: 16px;
  }

 .jspVerticalBar .jspArrow:focus {
 outline: medium none;
  }

.jspCorner {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEF4;
float: left;
height: 100%;
}

* html .jspCorner {
margin: 0 -3px 0 0;
 }

 .jspArrowUp
 {
 background-position: 0 0;
}

.jspArrowDown
{
 background-position: -15px 0 !important; /* twee pijlen in één png zetten */
}
.jspArrowDown.jspDisabled {
background-position: -15px -9px !important; /* twee pijlen in één png zetten */
}
.scroll-pane
{
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
z-index: 99;
}
```